# BotFramework getting 401 when using username:password in messaging endpoint - Web Chat

Tags: botframework, chatbot, azure-bot-service

I have a hubot running locally which is being served via ngrok. ngrok is started with auth.

Bot is configured correctly in azure active directory in app registrations and also in botframework.

When I am using webchat in botframework.com, I am getting unauthorized when ngrok is enabled with auth. Without auth it is working fine from botframework webchat.

Sample screenshot with auth not working (error in network tab) -
[image]

Sample screenshot without auth, working -
[image]

With curl request, auth is working. sample screenshot -
[image]

Stuck with this for past couple of days

Comment: You've tagged this with 'microsoft-teams' - how is this Teams related?

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow this botframework is integrated with ms-teams. And chats from ms teams are also getting 401. I get your point. Need to resolve connectivity issue first between botframework and backend. Removed "microsoft-teams"  tag.

Comment: I don't know much about hubit, but this result is usually the from of misconfiguration of your bot, especially the app id and app password from the Azure bot registration. In addition, why do you have "username+password" in the https address for ngrok?

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow we are putting a basic auth on our public url to which ms teams will send messages to in production. And in messaging endpoint there is no way to pass extra headers. This is to enforce extra layer of security to our publicly exposed dns and auth validation is done at our CDN provider. So to test this locally we've put auth in ngrok.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Teams doesn't support basic auth - where are you basing that off of?

Comment: Are you following any specific sample or have implemented on your own? Also, does the bot respond in 'Test in Web Chat' on Azure?